# Existence of Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Finite Dimensional Space over $\mathbb{F}$

Consider the Operator $T : V \rightarrow V$

Let $C_T$ and $M_T$ be the Characteristic and Minimal Polynomial of T respectively.

Suppose I know that $ C_T = M_T $ and $C_T$ is Irreducible

I'm confused here on how to show that T has no Non Trivial invariant subspaces. I know it has something to do with the Minimal or the Characteristic Polynomial of the restriction to the invariant space dividing the the original but I cant formalize it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Suppose $T$  has a non-trivial invariant subspace $W$ and consider the restriction of $T$ to $W$: its characteristic polynomial $\chi_{\substack{\phantom a\\W}}$ would be a non-trivial divisor of $C_T$.

Comment: So does the minimal polynomial part not matter here at all?

Comment: It's hard to say something general of the minimal polynomial of the restriction here, while it's easy to have inforemation on the characteristic polynomial: don't forget that if you take a supplementary subspace of $W$, you obtaian a block triangular matrix. Anyway, if $C_t$  is irreducible, it *is* the minimal polynomial.